# Grabbing previous and next element in an array

Tags: javascript

I am working on an image gallery.
Now I have some images like these

```
<ul id="moniqueGalList">
    <li><img class="moniqueThumbs" src="img/1Thumb.jpg" data-bigimgpath="img/1Full.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img class="moniqueThumbs" src="img/2Thumb.jpg" data-bigimgpath="img/2Full.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img class="moniqueThumbs" src="img/3thumb.jpg" data-bigimgpath="img/3Full.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img class="moniqueThumbs" src="img/4thumb.jpg" data-bigimgpath="img/4Full.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img class="moniqueThumbs" src="img/5thumb.jpg" data-bigimgpath="img/5full.jpg" alt=""></li>
</ul>
```

And using the click function i capture the current image clicked

```
for (var i = 0; i < moniqueThumbs.length; i++) {
    moniqueThumbs[i].addEventListener("click", grabBigImgPath);
}

function grabBigImgPath() {
    var currentThumbClicked = this;
}
```

How can I save the previous element and the next element in the array of moniqueThumbs (ie. varPrev and VarNext values)?

Comment: What do you mean by "save" them?

Comment: Separately: This might be a good use case for event delegation rather than hooking up a bunch of individual handlers.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes save in different vars i mean the whole img element. so i can grab the databigpath .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're saying that when a click occurs on one of these images, you want to set variables to the previous image (if any) and next image (if any).

If so, you can do this:

```
function grabBigImgPath() {
    var currentThumbClicked = this;
    var li = this.parentNode;
    var prevThumb = li.previousElementSibling && li.previousElementSibling.firstElementChild;
    var nextThumb = li.nextElementSibling && li.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild;
}
```

Those will be `null` if there is no previous or next element.

`previousElementSibling`/`nextElementSibling`/`firstElementSibling`: Your DOM structure is a series of `li` elements, each containing an `img`. The `li` elements are "sibling" elements (they share the same immediate parent). An element's `previousElementSibling` is the sibling element before it; its `nextElementSibling` is the element after it. `firstElementChild` is the first *child* element within an element.

IIRC, those DOM properties aren't supported in IE until IE9. If you have to support IE8, it's more of a pain, because you have to use `previousSibling`/`nextSibling`/`firstChild`, which can be non-`Element` nodes, which means you have to loop.

Live Example:

```js
var moniqueThumbs = document.querySelectorAll(".moniqueThumbs");
for (var i = 0; i < moniqueThumbs.length; i++) {

  moniqueThumbs[i].addEventListener("click", grabBigImgPath);
}

function grabBigImgPath() {
  var currentThumbClicked = this;
  var li = this.parentNode;
  var prevThumb = li.previousElementSibling && li.previousElementSibling.firstElementChild;
  var nextThumb = li.nextElementSibling && li.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild;
  
  snippet.log("Clicked: " + this.getAttribute("data-bigimgpath"));
  snippet.log("Previous: " + (prevThumb ? prevThumb.getAttribute("data-bigimgpath") : "(none)"));
  snippet.log("Next: " + (nextThumb ? nextThumb.getAttribute("data-bigimgpath") : "(none)"));
  snippet.logHTML("<hr>");
}
```

```html
<ul id="moniqueGalList">
  <li>
    <img class="moniqueThumbs" src="img/1Thumb.jpg" data-bigimgpath="img/1Full.jpg" alt="">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img class="moniqueThumbs" src="img/2Thumb.jpg" data-bigimgpath="img/2Full.jpg" alt="">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img class="moniqueThumbs" src="img/3thumb.jpg" data-bigimgpath="img/3Full.jpg" alt="">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img class="moniqueThumbs" src="img/4thumb.jpg" data-bigimgpath="img/4Full.jpg" alt="">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img class="moniqueThumbs" src="img/5thumb.jpg" data-bigimgpath="img/5full.jpg" alt="">
  </li>
</ul>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

More to explore in [the DOM core specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/).

**If** you have to support IE8, those loops I was talking about look like this:

```
function getPreviousElementSibling(element) {
    var prev;
    for (prev = element.previousSibling; prev; prev = prev.previousSibling) {
        if (prev.nodeType === 1) { // 1 = Element
            return prev;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

...which is why we have so many libraries like jQuery, YUI, etc. to help us with DOM traversal. :-)

Comment: no i didnt mean to capture LI. I want to capture images inside LI.

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini: That's what the above does. It gets the previous/next `li`, and then gets the `img` inside them.

Comment: Thanks but can you explain the previousSibling and all. please.

Comment: @Hey it returns [object HTMLImageElement]. can you please tell how can i grab the data attribute from prevThumb or nexttbhumb?

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini: Right, those are the `HTMLElement` instances for the `img` element. You use `getAttribute` to get an attribute from an `Element` (demonstrated in the live example I added a moment ago). I've also added a bit of explanation of those properties you asked about.

Comment: somehow the first and last image have probelms path. i dont know why??

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini: I don't know what you mean by "problems path." Since the first image has no previous image, as I mentioned above, that one will be `null`. Similarly the last image has no next image, so *that* one will be `null`.

Comment: so if i have to run some other code it wont run becuase of this error. how can i resolve that??

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini: Look at what I did in the live example: You test to make sure you didn't get `null`.